# Java variables declaration

Tags: java, android

I am a little bit confused about the program flow of an android activity, in java the main method executes first while in android the onCreate methods gets called first, so what about the variables which are defined at class level? How do they get declared/initialized when the activity starts executing, saying that onCreate gets called first. 
Also
Can we initialize these variables in Inner class and use their values outside of the inner class?

Comment: I think you should check the Activity lifecycle first! https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html

Comment: Have you looked in the file that is automatically generated?  `onCreate()` is definitely not the first line of code that is executed.

Comment: There is essentially a `main` method somewhere else in Android and that one does `new Activity()` and calls `activity.onCreate(someContext)`. The rest is standard java, class initialization is done once (i.e. `static` variables), then instance initialization (fields, constructors, ..)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually `OnCreate()` is the method get called first as you say. The Activity flows like this

`OnCreate` - >`OnStart` -> `OnResume`

At this point the Activity is visible to User

Similarly when Activity ends

`OnPause` -> `OnStop` ->`OnDestroy`

So answering your question. The variables in class level is not dependent, on these methods. Because its scope is for the whole Activity ie; from `OnStart` to `OnDestroy` . You can initialize them in `Oncreate` normally we do so. If you want to change there values on moving to next activity you should do that in `OnResume`. The  `Activity` Lifecycle is as follows

[image: Lifecycle]

You will have all the freedom for the rest as you do in java

Answer (score 0):

Typical variable initialization happens in `onCreate()` in Android. If the variable does not require any sort of Android `Context`, you can get away with initializing on the same line as the declaration.

Using inner classes can be sticky. They really shouldn't be changing the state of outer classes. You should initializing a variable within the same classes it's declared.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to access a variable from any where in the class then you should declare that variable class name declaration and you can initialize that variable from any where in your class concerning about your variable's value...below, there is sample outline...

```
class MainActivity extends Activity {

    //Declare your variable here

    @Override
    protected void onCreateActivity(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        //Initialize your variable here

   }

}
```